# Can not create app with yo angular fullstack

Tags: angular-fullstack

I have followed tutorial how to install generator angular full stack. Accordingly I have installed bower, yo, generator-angular-fullstack latest and grunt-cli globally. But after that when I tried to run command like D:\projectfolder> yo angular-fullstack I could not see any option further and back to again D:\projectfolder>

My operating system is Windows7. Please help me out from this.

Comment: Do you have node installed?

Comment: Yes I have installed Node, MongoDB. From command line I also run MongoDB with the appropriate command which run mongoDB successfully.